# IIS - Server an image in html put deny direct url access

Tags: image, security, iis, permissions

I run an IIS server and have an image directory that is used to display those images on a web page.

Is it possible to have it so the images can be displayed in the html e.g. in markup but not directly accessible via url e.g. domain.com/img/img.jpg

going to that url would be forbidden

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use configuration section. You could add below settings into your site's web.config file.

```
 <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
                <add segment="images" />
            </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

If you want to access the file directly from the browser, you will face below error.

[image]

Comment: Great thank you, does this require custom modules to be installed in IIS?

Comment: No, this is build-in feature which is used to prevent client user to access the bin folder.